# Extracting table from word files and save each table as a separate dataframe that should have the name of the respective word file

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Sorry if this is a repeated question . I have 100 words files from which i need to extract the table data.

Im using the below code for this :

```
import zipfile
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

def read_docx(docx_file, **kwargs):
    """Read tables as DataFrames from a Word document
    """
    ns = {'w': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}
    with zipfile.ZipFile(docx_file).open('word/document.xml') as f:
        root = etree.parse(f)
    for el in root.xpath('//w:tbl', namespaces=ns):
        el.tag = 'table'
    for el in root.xpath('//w:tr', namespaces=ns):
        el.tag = 'tr'
    for el in root.xpath('//w:tc', namespaces=ns):
        el.tag = 'td'
    return pd.read_html(etree.tostring(root), **kwargs)
```

So here I pass a single word file and Im able to save the data as a dataframe .

"docx_file " that is passed to the function is path of the word file . 
Eg. "C:\Test\123.docx"

But since I have 100 files, when i read a file it should extract the data and save the dataframe with the word file name :

Eg, If word file name is "123.docx" , I want my dataframe to be 123.docx. I want 100 similar dataframes .

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Do a dictionary of dataframes

```
import os

df_dict = dict()

#.....

filename = os.path.basename(docx_file)
df_dict[filename] = read_docx(docx_file)
```

And then you can access each datafrmae based on the key and the dictionary `df_dict`